# Remove Confirm Form Resubmission and corectness of AJAX PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, phpmailer

I have AJAX code which sends an email with PHPMailer without reloading the page. I don't want it in Jquery but in vanilla JS. The code works fine but after sending and refreshing the page it says "Confirm Form Resubmission". How to prevent this? Moreover, is this code correct? This is my first time creating something like AJAX and I hardly understand anything.

```
<?php
   require('mail.php'); //All PHPMailer lines here...
   $error = [];
   $msg = '';
   if(array_key_exists('email', $_POST )){
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];
      $mail->Username = 'email';
      $mail->Password = 'pass';
      $mail->setFrom('email');
      $mail->addAddress('email');
      if($mail->addReplyTo($email, $name)){
         $mail->Subject = $subject;
         $mail->isHTML(false);
         $mail->Body = <<<EOT
            Email: {$email}
            Name: {$name}
            Message: {$message}
         EOT;
      }
      // Check inputs
      if ($name=="") {
          $error[] = "A name is required.";
      }
      if ($subject=="") {
          $error[] = "A subject is required.";
      }
      if ($message=="") {
          $error[] = "A message is required.";
      }
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $error[] = "A valid email is required.";
      }
      if(empty($error)){
          if(!$mail->send()){
              $error[] = 'There was an error sending the mail. Please try again!';
          }
      }
  }
?>
```

```
<script>
    function doRegister(){
        let checks = {
            name : document.getElementById("mail-name"),
            email : document.getElementById("mail-email"),
            subject : document.getElementById("mail-subject"),
            message : document.getElementById("mail-message")
        },
        error = "";
        if(checks.name.value==""){
            error += document.getElementById("name-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A name is required!</p>';
        }
        if(checks.subject.value==""){
            error += document.getElementById("subject-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A subject is required!</p>';
        }
        if(checks.message.value==""){
            error += document.getElementById("message-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A message is required!</p>';
        }
        let pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if(!pattern.test(checks.email.value.toLowerCase())){
            error += document.getElementById("email-alert").innerHTML+='<p>A valid email is required!</p>';
        }
        // Ajax
        if(error!=""){
            error="";
        } else {
            let data = new FormData();
            for(let k in checks){
                data.append(k, checks[k].value);
            }
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', "", true);
            xhr.onload = function(){
                let res = <?php echo json_encode(['status' => count($error) == 0 ? 1 : 0, 'error' => $error]);?>;
                // SUCCESS!
                if (res.status) {
                    document.getElementById("success-alert").innerHTML+='<p>Success!</p>';
                } else {
                    // ERROR!
                    error = "";
                    for (let e of res['error']) {
                    error += e + "\n";
                    }
                    alert(error);
                }
            };
        // SEND
        xhr.send(data);
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return doRegister()">
   <input id="mail-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
   <span id="name-alert"></span>
   <input id="mail-email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
   <span id="email-alert"></span>
   <input id="mail-subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject">
   <span id="subject-alert"></span>
   <textarea id="mail-message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
   <span id="message-alert"></span>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   <span class="contact__form--alert-success" id="success-alert"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: For the browser to ask you to confirm a _re-submission_, you would have to have made a _normal_ submission in the first place. Which, if your AJAX part actually works as intended, should not have happened.

Comment: _“The code works fine but after sending and refreshing the page”_ - who is refreshing the page in this scenario and why - when you say you used AJAX to explicitly prevent the need to re-load the page?

Comment: @CBroe Maybe I wrote it wrong. I mean that when the button is pressed the email sends without refreshing. But if someone refreshes the page at that moment I get this alert "Confirm Form Resubmission".

Comment: Ok, now I see that even without clicking the button during refresh I have this alert...

Comment: So where could the error be...

Comment: How did you navigate _to_ this page then, that contains this form? Did that happen via a normal link - or is this page the “result” of a prior form submission maybe?

Comment: I don't quite understand. I have this site on localhost. Every time I go to it and refresh the page, I have this alert.

Comment: _How_ did you “go” to this page? Did you type the URL into the browser address bar directly? Or did you _navigate_ to it, from a different page of your project?

Comment: I type the URL into the browser bar, but does it matter in this case?

Comment: It _would_ matter, if you navigated to the page _via_ a form on a different page, that’s why I am asking, for clarification. But if that is not the case, then what you are saying is not actually explainable so far. Are you _absolutely_ sure, that the AJAX part worked? If there was any JS errors that would make the JS break in between, then your form would submit _normally_. Sending of the mail would probably still happen then, because the parameter names are the same, as when you send this via AJAX.

Comment: After removing the browser hostory, the problem magically disappeared... Ok, nice. What can you say about the code corectness?

Comment: How do you propose to block the ability to press the button multiple times which would cause the message to be sent multiple times. Maybe "display: none" on the form?

Comment: The usual way is to simply `disable` the button.

Comment: Does [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform-ajax.phps) help?

Comment: @Synchro Yes, this code is very useful, thanks!